# Excel 16, Windows 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with many sheets. The main tab holds a summary of all of the other sheets. What function in excel would allow me to reference a sheet by using the value of a cell.

For example, let's assume that the Main tab was called Main and that I had 2 sheets called Company A and Company B. On the main tab, I have 2 rows (one for Company A and another for Company B) and 4 columns (to capture 3 different data points for each company and one column with the company names) to summarize. The information I need will be in the exact same cells.

As opposed to going in manually and doing =Company A!B15, can I do a function that pulls the company name from a cell in the Main tab so the forumula would look like =(function to pull the value from cell B2, which is where the text "Company A" is)!B15. Then all I have to do is copy that formula down instead of linking in manually?

Answer (score 0):

Use INDIRECT which takes a string input and outputs a valid reference:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & B2 & "'!B15")
```

Note that the `B15` is part of a string and as such will act like an absolute reference, it will not change as the formula is copied down/across.

Also note that INDIRECT is volatile, meaning that when ever Excel recalculates this formula will do so also, regardless if the referenced cells have changed or not.  This can slow down the calc times if too many complex formulas are used.